# Sqljocky throws SocketException

Tags: dart

I'm trying to run the example for sqljocky(https://github.com/jamesots/sqljocky) but I am constantly getting the following error:

```
"SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 61, address = localhost, port = 54466"
```

Can someone explain how this may be remedied?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.

This is very likely the problem. If it doesn't help, just drop a comment :-)

Also, if this is the cause, but you still want to use `localhost`, a loopback adapter may be another solution. Tough I didn't test that myself, so I can't really say for sure.